# How to access media path with javascript for reliability?

Tags: magento2

I want to be able to access the view url path within javascript so I don't have to worry about linking via pub/var.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks can get the media path using `$block->getViewFileUrl('file/path');` and this can then be passed via a template to your javascript through a data-mage-init attribute or a text/x-magento-init script tag.

for example:

```
<div data-mage-init='
{
   "Namespace_Module/js/script": {
      "mediaUrl": "<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl() ?>"
   }
}
'></div>
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I tried. That's a shame, I thought there would be a better way.